# Creating a queue using a stack in Java

Tags: java, stack, queue

For an assignment, I must create a queue using stacks, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this code. I created a primary, alternative, and temporary stack. Every push, I want the value to be added into alternative, and everything currently in primary to be popped into temporary. Then, from temporary, I want all values to be popped into alternative, then change variables so that alternative is the main stack. Now, when I run this to test multiple values entered into the stack, I get an infinite loop with nothing output. I've been stuck on this for a while now so I was hoping I could get some help here. Here's the code.

```
Stack<Integer> mainStack = new Stack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> altStack = new Stack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> tmpStack = new Stack<Integer>();
public void push(int x) {
    altStack.add(x);
    while (mainStack.empty() == false){
        tmpStack.push(mainStack.pop());
    }
    while(tmpStack.empty() == false) {
        altStack.push(tmpStack.pop());
    }

    mainStack = altStack;
    altStack = tmpStack;
```

}

```
public int pop() {
    return mainStack.pop();
}

public int peek() {
    return mainStack.peek();
}

public boolean empty() {
    return mainStack.empty();
}
```

Comment: what happens to the old main stack reference after push? It's also easier to make push simple and do the stack transferring logic in pop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your idea seems to be to push everything from one stack into another to reverse the order of the elements. I cannot see how you get an infinite loop because you always pop and do it until empty. But two queues are enough to solve this using your idea:

```
Stack<Integer> mainStack = new Stack<>(); // elements pop in correct order
// the fake queue so to speak

public void push(int x) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>(); // temporary stack
    // reverse main stack
    while (!mainStack.empty())
        stack.push(mainStack.pop());
    // add x first (at the bottom) of the now empty main stack
    mainStack.push(x);
    // add the rest of the elements to main stack (preserving original order,
    // by reversing the elements again)
    while (!stack.empty())
        mainStack.push(stack.pop());
}
```